# Where does Ubuntu store shortcut keys?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have seen the files `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings` but in these file there are only names...

i.e.

```
<KeyListEntry name="move-to-workspace-1" description="Move window to workspace 1"></KeyList    Entry>
```

But how can I find out the key combination (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+.....)?